# TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA using self signed certificate and proxy.py?

Tags: python, linux, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to use a self signed certificate with [proxy.py](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py) (v2.3.1). I found [this](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py/issues/1268) issue but couldn't really find a solution there. My code is as follows:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get random available port to run proxy
    proxy_port = proxy.common.utils.get_available_port()

    # set up proxy to redirect all requests from the browser through the client
    with proxy.start(
            ['--host', '127.0.0.1',
             '--port', str(proxy_port),
             '--ca-cert-file', '/home/user/app/app-ca.pem',
             '--ca-key-file', '/home/user/app/app-ca.key',
             '--ca-signing-key-file', '/home/user/app/app-signing.key'],
            plugins=
            [b'header_modifier.BasicAuthorizationPlugin',
             header_modifier.BasicAuthorizationPlugin]):
        selenium_proxy.proxyType = ProxyType.MANUAL
        selenium_proxy.httpProxy = '127.0.0.1:' + str(proxy_port)
        selenium_proxy.sslProxy = '127.0.0.1:' + str(proxy_port)
        print('Proxy address: ' + selenium_proxy.httpProxy)
        run_app()
```

Where running the service I get:

```
Oct 26 14:56:32 raspberrypi python3[2727]: 2023-10-26 14:56:32,654 - pid:2727 [I] load_plugins:334 - Loaded plugin proxy.http.proxy.HttpProxyPlugin
Oct 26 14:56:32 raspberrypi python3[2727]: 2023-10-26 14:56:32,656 - pid:2727 [I] load_plugins:334 - Loaded plugin header_modifier.BasicAuthorizationPlugin
Oct 26 14:56:32 raspberrypi python3[2727]: 2023-10-26 14:56:32,656 - pid:2727 [I] load_plugins:334 - Loaded plugin __main__.BasicAuthorizationPlugin
Oct 26 14:56:32 raspberrypi python3[2727]: 2023-10-26 14:56:32,657 - pid:2727 [I] listen:115 - Listening on 127.0.0.1:42591
Oct 26 14:56:32 raspberrypi python3[2727]: 2023-10-26 14:56:32,692 - pid:2727 [I] start_workers:136 - Started 4 workers
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]: 2023-10-26 14:56:43,505 - pid:2733 [E] intercept:540 - OSError when wrapping client
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/proxy/http/proxy/server.py", line 529, in intercept
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:     self.wrap_client()
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/proxy/http/proxy/server.py", line 559, in wrap_client
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:     self.client.wrap(self.flags.ca_signing_key_file, generated_cert)
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/proxy/core/connection/client.py", line 43, in wrap
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:     ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1222, in wrap_socket
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:     suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:     session=session
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:     self.do_handshake()
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]:     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:1056)
Oct 26 14:56:43 raspberrypi python3[2727]: 2023-10-26 14:56:43,511 - pid:2733 [I] access_log:397 - 127.0.0.1:42880 - CONNECT firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com:443 - 0 bytes - 123.52 ms
```

It seems like it doesn't like my certificate as it's not issued from a trusted certificate authority as it's self signed. I created the certificate and keys like so using openssl:

```
openssl genrsa -out app-ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key app-ca.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out app-ca.pem
openssl genrsa -out app-signing.key 2048
chown user app-*
```

I tried adding the certificate to my systems trusted certificates like so:

```
cp app-ca.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/app-ca.crt
update-ca-certificates
```

which added it to `/etc/ssl/certs`:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

But the proxy setup still fails.

Additional info:

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v7l+ #1496 SMP Wed Dec 1 15:58:56 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```